# unable to resolve index out of range

Tags: python

i'm new to python and i'm trying to parse a list in `["+",1,3,3]` and then identify it's string operator `"+" "-" "x" "/"` and convert it into a question `{"qns": "1 + 3 + 3", "ans": 7}` and answer into a dictionary with just two key "qns and "ans"

So the question is there is a nested list as an input to the function. I'm supposed to convert each of the list to a dictionary output. The lists are identified by it's first string index "+" "-" "x" "/" and based on these strings,
i'm to output a dictionary based on its input with two keys, first is "qns" which is formatted according to its operator "+" -> 1 + 3 + 3 and "ans" -> 7
hence combining both into a dictionary which shows {"qns": "1 + 3 + 3", "ans": 7}

So far i'm only able to come up with this and i'm getting an error when i'm trying to parse in a smaller list `["x",3,2]` instead of `["+",1,3,3]`

Is there a better way to do this instead of an if-else statement?

```
    def math_qns(input):
        new_list = []
        for x in input:
            if x[0] == "+":
                if x[3]:
                    math = x[1] + x[2] + x[3]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2} {0} {3}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
                else:
                    math = x[1] + x[2]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2])
            if x[0] == "-":
                if x[3]:
                    math = x[1] - x[2] - x[3]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2} {0} {3}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
                else:
                    math = x[1] - x[2]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2])
            if x[0] == "x":
                if x[3]:
                    math = x[1] * x[2] * x[3]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2} {0} {3}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
                else:
                    math = x[1] * x[2]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2])
            if x[0] == "/":
                if x[3]:
                    math = x[1] / x[2] / x[3]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2} {0} {3}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
                else:
                    math = x[1] / x[2]
                    str_math = "{1} {0} {2}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2])
    
            qnsans = {
                "qns" : str_math,
                "ans" : math
            }
        
            new_list.append(qnsans)
        return print(new_list)

def main():
    input_list = [["+",1,3,3], ["-",2,5,-1], ["x",3,2],["/",12,3,2],["x",0,23],["+",1,2,3,4]]
    math_qns(input_list)
```

Ideally the outcome would be :

```
[{"qns": "1 + 3 + 3", "ans": 7},
{"qns": "2 - 5 - -1", "ans": -2},
{"qns": "3 x 2", "ans": 6},
{"qns": "12 / 3 / 2", "ans": 2},
{"qns": "0 x 23", "ans": 0},
{"qns": "1 + 2 + 3 + 4", "ans": 10}]
```

So far i've been getting an error

```
   if x[3]: 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Would be thankful for any advice as i've been stuck for quite some time over this trying to come up with a new way to make it more efficient and at the same time accomplish its objective.

Comment: Your Multiplication operation does not have index three so thats why it is throwing error!

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `if len(x) > 3` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying my best to understand, I have reframed this source code as best as I can understand. The if statements are necessary, but can be avoided if written differently. The index Error was caused by the 3rd item in the input where there are only 3 items, and you are trying to index the 4th item where there wasn't.

```
def math_qns(input):
    new_list = []
    for x in input:
        if x[0] == "+":
            math = sum(x[1:])
            
            str_math = " + ".join([str(i) for i in x[1:]])
        elif x[0] == "-":
            math = x[1]
            for i in x[2:]:
                math -= i
            str_math = " - ".join([str(i) for i in x[1:]])
        elif x[0] == "x":
            math = x[1]
            for i in x[2:]:
                math *= i
            str_math = " x ".join([str(i) for i in x[1:]])
        elif x[0] == "/":
            math = x[1]
            for i in x[2:]:
                math /= i
            str_math = " / ".join([str(i) for i in x[1:]]) 
        qnsans = {
            "qns" : str_math,
            "ans" : math
        }

        new_list.append(qnsans)
    return print(new_list)

def main():
    input_list = [["+",1,3,3], ["-",2,5,-1], ["x",3,2],["/",12,3,2],["x",0,23],["+",1,2,3,4]]
    print(math_qns(input_list))
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it is just to add all elements (besides the operator), to the question. Also don't name your variable built-ins (such as input).

Code:

```py
def math_qns(input_lists):
    new_list = []
    for input_list in input_lists:
        str_math = f" {input_list[0]} ".join(str(i) for i in input_list[1:])

        qnsans = {
            "qns" : str_math,
            "ans" : eval(str_math)
        }
        
        new_list.append(qnsans)

    print(new_list)
```